# vc++ community edition mongo db driver

Tags: mongodb, visual-c++, cmake, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I'mm trying to build mongocxx driver for vc++ 2017 community edition.
I ran below and got errors and retargetted to latest build tools and got successfully compiled.

```
  cd mongo-c-driver-1.8.0\src\libbson
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \
  "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" \
  "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" # Defaults to debug builds
```

But on running below errors even after retargetting windows SDK version 10.0.14393.

```
msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

I got below errors

Done Building Project "E:\nosql_db\mongo-c-driver-1.8.0\src\libbson\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"E:\nosql_db\mongo-c-driver-1.8.0\src\libbson\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"E:\nosql_db\mongo-c-driver-1.8.0\src\libbson\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(55,5): error MSB8020: The build
 tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please
install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting
 the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [E:\nosql_db\mongo-c-driver-1.8.
0\src\libbson\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]

Please let me know how shall i fix the problem.

What would be the easiest way to create the driver.

Comment: What do you mean by "retargeting windows SDK version 10.0.14393"?